# django-selectable dont work autocomplete

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to use django-selectable.

**model.py**:

```
    class Country(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(verbose_name='Страна', max_length=128, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Region(models.Model):
    country   = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='Город')
    name      = models.CharField(verbose_name='Город', max_length=128, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name   

class City(models.Model):
    country   = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='Город')
    region    = models.ForeignKey(Region, verbose_name='Регион')
    name      = models.CharField(verbose_name='Город', max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Lookup.py**:

```
from subscribers.models import City
from selectable.base import ModelLookup
from selectable.registry import registry


class CityLookup(ModelLookup):
    model = City
    search_fields = ('name__icontains', )

registry.register(CityLookup)
```

**forms.py**:

```
import selectable.forms as selectable
from subscribers.models import City
from partners.lookup import CityLookup



class ShowSomeForm(forms.Form):
    autocomplete = forms.CharField(
        label='Type the name of a fruit (AutoCompleteWidget)',
        widget=selectable.AutoCompleteWidget(CityLookup),

    )
```

**view.py**

```
...     
        form = ShowSomeForm()      
        return render(request, 'personal_accout_partners.html', {'formPart': formPartners, 'formMes': formMessages, 'form': form})
```

**personal_accout_partners.html**

```
{{form}}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/
1.8.13/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

However, this code doesn't work (in `//selectable/partners-citylookup/` I have this):

```
{"data": [{"id": 3161, "label": "РђРєС‚Р°С€", "value": "РђРєС‚Р°С€"}, {"id": 3162, "label": "РђРєСѓС‚РёС…Р°", "value": "РђРєСѓС‚РёС…Р°"}, {"id": 3163, "label": "РђР»РµР№СЃРє", "value": "РђР»РµР№СЃРє"}, {"id": 3164, "label": "РђР»С‚Р°Р№СЃРєРёР№", "value": "РђР»С‚Р°Р№СЃРєРёР№"}, {"id": 3165, "label": "Р‘Р°РµРІРѕ", "value": "Р‘Р°РµРІРѕ"}, {"id": 3166, "label": "Р‘Р°СЂРЅР°СѓР»", "value": "Р‘Р°СЂРЅР°СѓР»"}, {"id": 3167, "label": "Р‘РµР»РѕРІРѕ", "value": "Р‘РµР»РѕРІРѕ"}, {"id": 3168, "label": "Р‘РµР»РѕРєСѓСЂРёС…Р°", "value": "Р‘РµР»РѕРєСѓСЂРёС…Р°"}, {"id": 3169, "label": "Р‘РµР»РѕСЏСЂСЃРє", "value": "Р‘РµР»РѕСЏСЂСЃРє"}, {"id": 3170, "label": "Р‘РёР№СЃРє", "value": "Р‘РёР№СЃРє"}, {"id": 3171, "label": "Р‘Р»Р°РіРѕРІРµС‰РµРЅСЃРє", "value": "Р‘Р»Р°РіРѕРІРµС‰РµРЅСЃРє"}, {"id": 3172, "label": "Р‘РѕСЂРѕРІР»СЏРЅРєР°", "value": "Р‘РѕСЂРѕРІР»СЏРЅРєР°"},
```

What can I do about this problem?

Comment: please elaborate on what exactly doesn't work, are you getting an exception or a javascript error in the debug console (if so, include it in the question),

Comment: tutuDajuju, form in temlates doesn't autocomplite when i writing in field( May be i dont understand something important. If you have simple example, write please)